# Cloud Firestore security rules with conditions from Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I had already saved all data like users or rooms contents on Firebase Database. Now I want to move all posts to Cloud Firestore for better queries.

But,

Can I take conditions from Realtime Database?

I mean all users data are in realtime database. So I want to get some informations from there, then decide whether it's accessible or not.

Answer (score 0):

The security rule systems are different between Realtime Database and Firestore.  There is currently no easy to way to simply copy from one to the other, or to make one recognize the other.  If you're porting your data to Firestore, you'll have to write new rules by hand that functionally match the ones you were using in Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't functionality that exists. You'll need to have migrated the data that the rules depend upon to Cloud Firestore first.